# What is the integral for this function?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I integrate the following function and what is the resulting integrated function?

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t \cdot \lambda_S} \cdot \sum_{x=k}^{n} \binom{n}{x} \cdot e^{-t \cdot \lambda_P \cdot x} \cdot (1-e^{-t \cdot \lambda_P})^{n-x} dt$$

for positive $\lambda_S, k, n, \lambda_P$.

Comment: If $k$ is zero then the summation would be equal to $1$ binomial expansion

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained where this expression comes from. It looks like some probability that a random variable is greater than some value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral sounds a little cumbersome, but the following hint may help.

**Partial Hint**

$$(1-e^{-t \cdot \lambda_P})^{n-x}=\sum_{l=0}^{n-x}\binom{n-x}{l}(-1)^{l}e^{-l\lambda_P t}$$therefore$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t \cdot \lambda_S} \cdot e^{-t \cdot \lambda_P \cdot x} \cdot (1-e^{-t \cdot \lambda_P})^{n-x} dt=\sum_{l=0}^{n-x}\binom{n-x}{l}(-1)^{l}\int_0^\infty e^{-t \cdot \lambda_S}e^{-t \cdot \lambda_P \cdot x} e^{-\lambda_p l t}dt\\=\sum_{l=0}^{n-x}\binom{n-x}{l}(-1)^{l}\cdot {1\over \lambda_S+\lambda_P  x+\lambda_p l}$$and by substituting we can write$$\text{The desired integral}=\sum_{x=k}^{n}\binom{n}{x}\sum_{l=0}^{n-x}\binom{n-x}{l}(-1)^{l}\cdot {1\over \lambda_S+\lambda_P  x+\lambda_P l}$$

Comment: That's great, thank you! I just think the first binomial $\binom{n}{x}$ is missing between the sums. Isn't it? As in $$\sum_{x=k}^{n}\binom{n}{x}\sum_{l=0}^{n-x}\binom{n-x}{l}(-1)^{l}\cdot {1\over \lambda_S+\lambda_P  x+\lambda_P l}$$

Comment: isn't there a term missing in the integrated function? I am getting incompatible/counter-intuitive values with this function. However, when I include the apparently missing term $\binom{n}{x}$, I get values that make more sense. Could you comment on it? Thank you!

Comment: Oh. yes and sorry for late answer. I fixed that up :)